# Is it possible to get rid of expo completely

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using react native expo 47 and I wanted to eject from expo to have native modules for ios and android to use my native code or 3rd libraries. But on 47 sdk expo there is no eject. Instead it I could make prebuild which generated for me native folders for ios and android. But when i want to use any library which use native code i have exception that its not defied sdk in gradle etc. How to get rid of expo completely and use react native cli? There is way to migrate from expo to cli without any expo requirements?

I remember that in older expo sdk it was eject prcess which allow you to do whatever you want in project. I want to achieve the same solution.
I want to migrate from expo to react native cli with no expo dependencies and rules, to work with native codes.